# Some understanding regarding Extension Methods

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I just collected some knowledge regarding and it seems to be very little to understand following scenario.

I have 2 classes. One has `Main` method and other has two `Extension Methods` as follow.

**Class having Main**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string uuu = "214";
            Console.WriteLine(uuu.SplitMe().AddMe());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

**Extension Class**

```
static class ExtensionClass
    {
        public static char[] SplitMe(this string value)
        {
            return value.ToCharArray();
        }

        public static long AddMe(this char[] value)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i<value.Length ; i++)
            {
                sum += Convert.ToInt32(value[i]);
            }
            return sum;
        }
    }
```

I was expecting, in following line

```
Console.WriteLine(uuu.SplitMe().AddMe());
```

output of `uuu.SplitMe()` to be `char[]` of {'2','1','4'} and result of complete line to be printed as 7 (2+1+4) but it is 151 on my console. Could you please elaborate how its being calculated?

Thanks.

Comment: this has nothing to do with extension methods

Comment: Use [`Int32.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) instead

Comment: '2' is has not the value of 2. If you convert '2' to a number, you will get the ACII code for the letter '2'. If you want to parse a number use `Int32.Parse`.

Comment: @thefiloe .NET generally uses the Unicode character set and the UTF-16   and UTF-8 encodings. You can only get ASCII codes if you explicitly use ASCII conversion methods (or depend on their numerical equivalence but that leads to errors with characters not supported by ASCII).

Comment: If you do something like (int)'2' you will get the ACII code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that a `System.Char` value of `'2'` has an integer value of 50, not 2.  As such, you're summing `{'2','1','4'}`, which have values of `{50, 49, 52}`, which in turn becomes 151.

You could convert the characters to numbers matching their value via:

```
sum += int.Parse(value[i].ToString());
```

However, this will raise an exception if you pass a string that contains non-numeric characters.

Answer (score 1):

The value of a `char` containing `2` is not 2, but 50, as its position in the [ASCII table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is used as its value; the same goes for the other numbers, which explains the unexpected result.

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToInt32` does not convert the numeric string value, but [the specified Unicode character to the equivalent 32-bit signed integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww9t2871%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Because the ascii value of 2 is 50  1 is 49 and 4 is 52. so it is adding those values..

you need to change your code

`public static long AddMe(this char[] value)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
            {
                sum +=  value[i]-48;
            }
            return sum;
        }`

or you can do this also

```
sum += int.Parse(value[i].ToString());
```